# How to make a route with hashtag href in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have menu links which points to different pages with css animation. My anchor tag is look like this

I create a route for this link but it does not work.

```
<a href="#about" class="icon-a fas fa-user-tie"></a>

"Route::get('#about',function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

can any one please help me to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: the hash part of the URL is client side

Comment: yes, it is part of the client side.

Comment: it is only client side, it isn't part of the path sent to the server, even if it was it is for reference of the page you are on, not a page itself

Comment: maybe, I did not explain my question very well. I want a Route when I click on About link it should take me to about page.

Comment: then make a route for the path `'about'`

Comment: I did, it does not route to that page and my animation also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the fragment is processed by the client, the client must be able to render JavaScript before the fragment can be accessed. A solution to accomplish this might be:

In your `routes.php` file:

```php
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('basic-javascript-router');
});

Route::get('/about', function() {
    return view('about');
});

Route::get('/welcome', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

In your project's `/resources/views/` directory add a simple `basic-javascript-router.php` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>rerouting</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkHash() {
            if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash === '#about') {
                window.location.href = '/about';
            } else {
                //direct users to the generic landing page
                window.location.href = '/welcome';
            }
        }
        window.onload = checkHash;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>rerouting...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Typically this is a job for a frontend framework like VueJS but this might work for you.

Comment: you are awesome Casey. Thanks a lot